# When std::vector reallocate its memory array, is copy constructor or move constructor used?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector

When std::vector reallocate its memory array, what kind of copy / move constructor is used to copy / move elements to new houses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the move-constructor exists and is `noexcept` then it is used.  Otherwise the copy-constructor is used.

Using a move-constructor that might throw is undesirable as it might happen that some objects are moved to the new storage and then an exception prevents the rest of the objects being moved.

The cppreference.com site does say that if the object is non-copyable , but has a non-noexcept move constructor, then it will use that move-constructor, with "unspecified behaviour" if an exception is thrown. I guess that means elements may be lost from the vector.

Comment: The documentation at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) doesn't entirely agree with what you are saying. If T's move constructor is not noexcept and T is not CopyInsertable into *this, vector will use the throwing move constructor. If it throws, the guarantee is waived and the effects are unspecified.

Comment: @RSahu That documentation refers to an element being inserted; this question is about the behaviour for elements already in the vector. E.g. consider `v.reserve( v.capacity() + 1 );`

Comment: [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) uses the same wording.

Comment: @RSahu  I guess that is saying that non-copyable objects with throwing move constructor will use that constructor and waive the strong guarantee, but I'm not really sure what the behaviour would be in case of an exception. E.g. it seems to me that objects will be lost from the vector.

Comment: It sounds like the standard takes the safe route and resorts to unspecified behavior.

Comment: @RSahu Yeah, "unspecified behaviour" means some limited range of options but it's not clear to me what exactly the options are here.

Comment: For what its worth, [looks like move constructor is called on gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/vAsNMm)